# I'm going on an Easter Egg hunt. Have I missed anything?

Tags: dying-light, dying-light-the-following

I've been playing Dying Light and Dying Light The Following for a long while now. I beat the game, found all the skins, everything, but there is on set that I believe I haven't completed.

The Easter Eggs.

I've found:

- the dead shallow-diver in the water off the coast (Not sure where.),
- the Clicker Zombie based off of The Last of Us,
- the exploding Teddy Bear,
- the Alien Gun,
- the Pyza Suit,
- the Plants vs Zombies secret,
- the duplication glitch,
- the through-the-wall glitch,
- the Destiny 2 loot cave,
- the EXPcalibur,
- the Korek Machete,
- the Tolga's Folley Button (But for some reason it won't take me to the Harran Power Plant.),
- the Paper Airplane.

And I believe there were a few more that I found but I can't remember them at the moment. If there are any Easter Eggs that weren't on this list, could someone tell me what and where they are? Or even just what they are.

Comment: @Arghtype Thanks for the edit. Sorry about not having the correct list ordering. I can't figure out how to make the listing dots.

Comment: np, here is our formatting guide  https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: I have vague memories of two tiny pebbles you're supposed to find that give you a weird telekinetic grenade-style weapon.

Comment: Oh yeah I've been trying to find the second one for a while. Basically, they're two little pebbles called the eyes of(Name here.)Globa or something. Once you collected both of them, you put them in a skull that belongs to some musician, and you basically get the Toad zombie's vomit grenade thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest one you missed is The Dancing Zombies Easter egg which can only be completed while you escort the survivor who claims to be a werewolf. Flip a switch in one of of the hangars at the railyard and watch them dance!

You can visit the Left4Bread store in the slums (near the first Safehouse you unlock)
Likewise, visit the Bites Motel also in the slums where you saved that Kristov on the bus in The Prodigal Son side quest

Be sure to pick up the Airstrike developer weapon from the crashed aircraft in the Radio Tower area (same zone as the Plants VS Zombies Easter egg)

Detonate the SECOND NUKE in the Countryside (look up a tutorial on how to do this)

Lastly, be sure to collect the buried Charley DVDs and collect the Chicken Sword

Check out the [Wikia Page](https://dyinglight.fandom.com/wiki/Easter_Eggs) for more Easter eggs. Good night and good luck

EDIT:

Other Developer Weapons I missed:

Stasis field - grenade that causes zombies to float, activate two pebbles - one in the slums, one in old town

Sick Grenade: Play checkers on the roof of The Tower

Comment: There were a few of those that I did find, such as the Stasis Field, The Bites Motel and Left4Bread, Airstrike, and the Dancing Zombies. I've never heard of the Second Nuke though. And I believe I've heard of the Charley DVDs and the chicken sword, I just haven't found them yet. And thank you. I'll be sure to check them out!

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it. The two hidden pebbles I mentioned are for the "Right  Hand of Glova" Easter egg. Add that to your list too.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you.

Comment: I know it's been a few months, but please remember to mark this answer as "accepted" if you found it helpful

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry about that. I forgot I made this question.